# Looking for a recommended Unit Test design approach when I need to process complex and large XML files

Tags: unit-testing

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Unit Test Projects.

I have an application that reads complex XML files, and do some processing based on XPATH queries in their data. I need to build a series of unit tests for my application. Below two options come to my mind:

**Option #1**: Include a few selected XML files as part of the Unit Test Project.

Create unit tests that reads the files, and tests specific scenarios.
This is the most intuitive and easiest option for me. Because I can include many complex scenarios in my selected XML files update them as required, then build all the required unit tests.

**Option #2**: Create mock classes that provide specific XML data scenarios

I need to create a few mock classes that provide specific XML data scenarios.  The application needs to be updated such that it gets the data through classes in an IoC container.

To me, Option#1 is quite simple, but I wanted to get more information on the Option#2

**Question**:
Are above two options aligned with Unit Test design best practices? What is the most optimal Unit Test design for my senatio?

Answer (score 0):

What is best depends a lot on your specific needs.  However, typically you would strive for tests that run fast, execute in different environments (not only your machine), are deterministic etc.

To me it seems that option #1, while probably being the fastest to implement, has negative impact on test execution (file access takes some time), makes the test execution dependent on the environment (permissions to the file, which directory?, file name encoding, ...), can lead to non-deterministic behaviour (file being locked due to a parallel test process running) etc.

In contrast, option #2 will likely cost you more implementation effort initially.  There are, however, mechanisms to make it less costly: You can implement helper functions to create typical XML content, such that several test cases can benefit from these common helper functions etc.